# Change the title of default titlebar provided by Navigationview

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to change the the default title of the titlebar provided by NavigationView?
Or, disable the entire default titlebar which is provided while using NavigationView?

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code fore help (how you define your NavigationView and how your push the view into this navigation view).

Comment: I'm not sure you can disable it on any individual view within the navigationview. You could, however, detect that you were on this particular view within the navigationview and use CSS to hide that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [navigationBar](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-cfg-navigationBar) configuration to customise, or hide the default titleBar.

```
navigationBar: {
    hidden: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To hide the navigation bar**

```
Ext.getCmp('idNavigationBar').setHidden(true);
or 
Ext.getCmp('idNavigationBar').hide();
or
Ext.Componentquery.Query('#idNavigationBar')[0].hide();
```

**And to make it visible**

```
Ext.getCmp('idNavigationBar').setHidden(false);
or
Ext.getCmp('idNavigationBar').show();
or
Ext.Componentquery.Query('#idNavigationBar')[0].show();
```